# Thai string manipulation issues caused by incorrect string length

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8, thai

I am trying to highlight some substring in a Thai text:

```
high = high.Insert(myString.Index + myString.Length + "<b>" + currentLength, "</b>");
```

The issue is, that the `myString` string contains a special Thai character ("เงินฝาก"). The given string should have a length of 7, but the length is resolved as 6. Which highlights the text only partially, not including the last character.

I've tried encoding the string (both the high and `myString` string). But it didn't work. Do you have any tips on how to handle this? I've also tried the `Replace` method, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested `String.Length` with `เงินฝาก` and it returned `7`, not `6`.

Comment: Hi, thanks looking into it. It's possible, that when I copied the string into the editor, it chopped up the characters. Here is a screenshot of my code in the debug mode: [link](http://i.imgur.com/NYpmQKh.png) notice the watched variables

Comment: How do you calculate the length?  I cannot read Thai, but selecting one glyph at a time in my browser I count six glyphs in your string.  Is there a combining character in there?

Comment: I cannot read Thai too, so I am on the same page on this one. It looks like the first character is a combining one. I can see my cursor getting stuck in the middle of the first character, when opening it in a different editor: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Z86fjBi.png). I also tried to set the thread to InvariantCulture, but it didn't help. The thread culture is set to Thai.

Comment: ok, so it seems like the two strings are encoded differently. Here is a screenshot on a character by character comparison and apparently, the third character is nit the same: [character compare](http://i.imgur.com/EjhEuoe.png)

Comment: Do you use regular expression to search for `เงินฝาก`? If yes, it look like your problems is a regular expression pattern since it does not captured the Thai special alphabet.

Comment: I'm Thai, and I can tell that your `searchedText` is the misspelled one. Could you give some snippet we can run to reproduce the issue? I tried to reproduce using `Regex` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The easy concept is to ignore the counting of the superscript and subscript Thai character like as the example code below:

```
    public int ThaiLength(string text)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int l = text.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        {
            if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(text[i]) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                ++c;
        }

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: -1, sorry: (1) the code looks like a blatant hack; (2) a correct approach should use `char.GetUnicodeCategory()`, not a hardcoded stuff; (3) even for manual counting, it is sufficient to call `text.ToCharArray().Length` just once, no need for loop; (4) yet more, it is terribly ineffective to call `ToCharArray()` in the loop.

Comment: very good !! char.GetUnicodeCategory() can be used to check the counting length instead of hard code text string.