# How to get length of Thai string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding

I am facing issues while calculating length of strings that contain Thai characters.
In the below image from Notepad++, we need a way in c#/.NET to get the Document Length value (170) for the provided string -

[image: Thai String Issue]

String.Length works well for English Language/Characters, but for this example ("บ.อินเตอร์เทค+สเปคเชียวตี้+กลาส+จำกัด+28%2f10+หมู่+1+ต.+คลองอุดมชลจร") - it returns length as 69, instead of 170.
Is there a way in c#/.NET to get the actual length of string values for non-English languages?

I tried using Encodings as well, but no luck. Any pointers/help on this will be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`Encoding.GetByteCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytecount)

Comment: See if these links help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40307732/421195, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952586/421195.  Q: Can you show us the C# code that reads the string?  Q: Do you know the encoding type when you read the string?  UTF8?  UTF16?  Other?

Comment: [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AcQBsB7AIwEMqBLALweGZqgG49CS5ACoBTAB7A+ufpmIBnIgF4SqAESAsODKBaOEAscIEw4QAJwgVDgtgYjhAMnAHA6HCAQOESAqOAOBsOBsHAUHCBWOEBEcIHI4Ix8BJOERAQDhAUjhAJjh7REAIOEBmOGDARjhAFDhEdAAOAFJ0ADNZREBqOEBCOEBOOEAJOERMRCMyRBtQrUBwOC1ADjgkwrdQ6NM8VSkZAE4ACgASVQBVIQAxAFo0ojoAT2ARORAiAG8AUSgAYxo4ZigAczIJybTKEWAAISWRAGEaaGBBuQBKAF9VN6lSIdGADJXZZgVYbKAiADuRAAysAwIcjgBJKDZGivN5kIHHYAACxRogkmyoIgAtiIoMA5F8fnggA===)

Comment: Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount() solves the purpose for me.
Thank you everyone for the quick responses & time. Appreciate all your help on this.

Comment: Code-point vs character vs byte: learn up what each means, then it will become obvious

Comment: You might want to throw "Extended Grapheme Cluster" and "glyph" into the list of stuff to learn

Comment: thank you for suggestions Charlieface and canton7, I will check on these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

69 is correct, though.

`บ.อินเตอร์เทค+สเปคเชียวตี้+กลาส+จำกัด+28%2f10+หมู่+1+ต.+คลองอุดมชลจร` contains 69 characters; the UTF-8 encoding of it is 170 bytes long.

Notepad++ is showing you the length of the encoded content.

If you do need the encoded length, use [`Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytecount?view=net-6.0#system-text-encoding-getbytecount(system-string)).

Comment: As I select that string character-by-character, I count only 58 characters, not 69. It's likely those diacritics are being represented as combining marks

Comment: Also note that the 170 figure includes the trailing newline. The string in your answer is only 169 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, in notepad (or notepad++) the column indicator shows the character count, including combining marks.  When you move past a character that combines several unicode diacritics the column counter advances by more than one character.  This `มู่` character, for example, counts as three (0x0E21, 0x0E39, 0x0E48).

Comment: `อิ` consists out of two chars for example, its not `อ`.